# Excel: "Get cell date and copy to the other sheet" Using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets. Where the sheets were named as Sheet1 & Sheet2.

This is my sample data located at ***Sheet1***

```
         A | B
 29-Nov-19 | 2
 30-Nov-19 | 2
```

And

Here's my sample data located at ***Sheet2***

```
         A | B
           | 2
           | 2
```

The formula that I placed in Sheet2 Column B
is

=Sheet1!B2:B3

But when I tried to put this formula in Sheet2 column A
Excel gives me an error like this

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused - do you want data validation or not? This doesn't sound like a programming question.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the data from Sheet1 to Sheet2. whether the data has the data validation or not?

Comment: The formula to use in Sheet B2 is =Sheet1!B2. Then copy that formula from B2 to B3.

Comment: The parameter B works with that formula but in the parameter A. Keeps showing the above error. Maybe because the data is formatted as date?

Comment: No, not because the data is formatted as Date. You get this error because there is a data validation applied to the cell. Activate the cell and go (on the ribbon) to Data - Data validation. Check which validation applies and adapt (or delete) as required.

Comment: It works! Thanks :)